# IOException with Runtime.exec after Java upgrade

Tags: java, linux

I have the following code that executes an external binary (mysqldump in my case):

```
        String osName = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
        String path = "";
        String backupFilePath = backupDir + System.getProperty("file.separator") + "jlawyerdb-dump.sql";

        if (osName.contains("win")) {

        } else if (osName.contains("linux")) {
            path="/usr/bin/";
        } else if (osName.startsWith("mac")) {
            path = "/usr/local/mysql/bin/";
        }

        log.info("MySQL Dump: " + path + "mysqldump");
        
        String[] cmd = null;
        if ("".equals(password) || password == null) {
            cmd = new String[]{
                path + "mysqldump",
                "-P",
                port,
                "-u" + user,
                "-r",
                backupFilePath,
                "jlawyerdb"
            };
        } else {
            cmd = new String[]{
                path + "mysqldump",
                "-P",
                port,
                "-u" + user,
                "-p" + password,
                "-r",
                backupFilePath,
                "jlawyerdb"
            };
        }

        Runtime shell = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process process = null;

        File f = new File(backupFilePath);
        int exitCode = 0;
        try {

            if (f.exists()) {
                f.delete();
            }

            process = shell.exec(cmd);
            exitCode = process.waitFor();

            f.setLastModified(System.currentTimeMillis());

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error(ex);

        }
```

This code works well when executed with Java 8, but on the same system fails when executing with Java 17 (Liberica JDK).

An IOException is raised (error=13, permission denied). The binary is executable for the user that runs the Java process. The target directory is owned by the user that runs the process. Happens on Ubuntu.

I am out of ideas on where to analyze further. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Update: I have extracted the code to a minimalistic main class. The shell output below demonstrates behavior with Java 8 and Java 17:

```
root@j-lawyer-box:/usr/local/j-lawyer-server# java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_352"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_352-8u352-ga-1~22.04-b08)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.352-b08, mixed mode)

root@j-lawyer-box:/usr/local/j-lawyer-server# java DumpTest 
MySQL Dump: /usr/bin/mysqldump

root@j-lawyer-box:/usr/local/j-lawyer-server# ./jre/bin/java -version
openjdk version "17.0.9" 2023-10-17 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.9+11-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.9+11-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)

root@j-lawyer-box:/usr/local/j-lawyer-server# ./jre/bin/java DumpTest 
MySQL Dump: /usr/bin/mysqldump
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/bin/mysqldump": error=13, Keine Berechtigung
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1143)
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1073)
        at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:594)
        at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:453)
        at DumpTest.main(DumpTest.java:58)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=13, Keine Berechtigung
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.forkAndExec(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:314)
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:244)
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1110)
        ... 4 more
```

The values in the cmd array that is passed to Runtime.exec look like this:

```
/usr/bin/mysqldump
-P
3306
-uroot
-psecretvalue
-r
/usr/local/j-lawyer-server/backups/jlawyerdb-dump.sql
jlawyerdb
```

Comment: @tgdavies thanks for the comment. I added terminal output of a Java 8 run vs. a Java 17 run.

Comment: What happens when run from the command line?

Comment: @g00se works fine on the command line, running as the same user as the one that runs the java process...

Comment: Sure it's identical? Dump the command array

Comment: Print the command and exit code to confirm both run worked, and print stdout+stderr streams before `waitFor` to see if there are other clues about the differences (easier if you use ProcessBuilder instead of Runtime.exec).

Comment: @g00se I added the output of he command array in the question.

Comment: @DuncG the only additional information I get from stdout / stderr is "mysqldump: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.". With Java 17 i do not get this output because the binary does not seem to be invoked at all. With Java 8 the exit code is 0, with Java 17 i do not get an exit code because IOException is thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used strace to figure out what was going on under the hood. It showed a variety of libraries being searched and loaded from jre/lib. I then compared the attributes of this folder between the two JREs involved, and there were differences. The solution for me was to perform a

```
chmod a+x <JRE-FOLDER>/lib/jspawnhelper
```